# New features in Kohana 3? Is it a wise decision to use ver 3 instead of 2?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I have used ver 2 before but i'm thinking of using ver 3 for my new project. Is it advisable to use ver 3 at this point event when it's not yet stable?

Comment: A short discussion on this took place back in Nov. '09 on this very question: http://forum.kohanaphp.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=4108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your situation.

**New projects** will usually go this way.

```
Kohana 3 -> 3.0.1 -> 3.0.2 -> 3.0.3 etc ...
```

**Old projects** using Kohana 2.3.4 will *probably* use this path instead:

```
Kohana 2.3.4 -> 2.4 (API Change) -> 2.4.1 etc ...
```

I'd personally choose Kohana 3 for a new project as it has new features such as reverse routing, [HMVC](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/) and some other stuff that's vanished from my head at this time.

It's production ready and I've already used it on a few projects.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial wiki, http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php, out to discuss the new features in Kohana ver3. And from what's been said, its pretty stable and ready for production.